# Looping my javascript logic over files within a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, curl, module.exports

How would I loop this script over files within a folder? So that my curl function uploads all the transcript and audio files to this website via an automated approach. (lower quality gentle is a website that allows for it's users to extract json objects from transcripts and even lets us find start and end times of sentences via audio.)

```
 const getAligned = require('./getAudioTranscript.js');  // require getAudioTranscript.js, file ext not required, but need ./ to indicate it is a local file
    getAligned.writeFile('_rJOSDgDG0A.m4a', '_rJOSDgDG0A.txt');

    module.exports = {
            //var request = curl.request(default_options);
            writeFile: (audioFilePath, textFileName) => {
                const curl = require('curlrequest');
                let options = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    form: [
                        "audio=@" + audioFilePath,
                        "transcript=@" + textFileName
                    ],
                    url: 'http://localhost:32768/transcriptions?',
                };
                let startDate = new Date().getTime();
                console.log(startDate);
                curl.request(options, function (err, data, meta) {
                    //res.send({ alignment: data });
                    console.log(options);
                    //del.sync([textFileName]);
                    let endDate = new Date().getTime();
                    console.log((endDate - startDate) / 1000);
            });
        },
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get all the files in the directory. This can be done in node.js using `fs.readdir(path, callback)`. The callback accepts a function with an error and a file array that contains the name of all the files.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

fs.readdir('dir_path', (err, files) => {
    //check error

    for (const file of files) {
        //check if it is a .m4a file, so that every pair gets only send once
        if (path.extname(file) === '.m4a') {
            const txt_file= path.basename(file, '.m4a') + '.txt';
            getAligned.writeFile(path.join('dir_path', file), path.join('dir_path', txt_file));
        }
    }
});
```

More info in the [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback)